# Rankx Measure with countrows returns 1

Tags: powerbi

Can someone help what is wrong in this DAX expression where it just returns 1 when used in visual.

```
Measure = var _countif=calculate(COUNTROWS(FILTER('28Jun_1973',[Rcode]='28Jun_1973'[Rcode])))
var measure_rank = RANKX(all('28Jun_1973'),_countif,,,Dense)
return measure_rank
```

here is my sample data:

| ID | RCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | AAA |
| 1001 | AAA |
| 1002 | AAB |

Comment: What is your expected output? And I don't think this code `[Rcode]='28Jun_1973'[Rcode]` is meaningful since you are filtering the row to itself...

Comment: | ID      | Rcode   |Measure(rank)  |
| --------| ------- |---------------|
| 1000    | AAA     |1              |
| 1002    | AAA     |1              |
| 1003    | AAB     |2              |

Comment: I cannot create a proper table here but once the measure is used in visual of power bi, then it would have entries 1, 1, 2 for Rcode AAA, AAA, AAB.        This is because the counts are 2, 2, 1.

Comment: Did you try to add column for the ranking and then used in powerbi visual report or you can only used in measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the right expression.

```
RANKX(ALL('28Jun_1973'[Rcode]),calculate(COUNTROWS(FILTER('28Jun_1973',[Rcode]='28Jun_1973'[Code]))),,,Dense)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rankIdByCode =
RANKX (
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'tbl', 'tbl'[code] ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'tbl'[id] ) ),
    ,
    ASC
)
```

dax measure

Comment: Please provide more info how this works. code only answers are considered low quality